# link javascript with gwt widget

Tags: javascript, gwt, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I am creating datepicker using
1- bootstrap datepicker js/css files to popup the datepicker (localted in the web directory and included in the html file)
2- gwt to create the textbox widget where the date should be filled

the issue I am facing that the js is not able to identify the textbox that I am creating in GWT , while if I am inserting the text box directly in the html file the datepicker is working file (js is working)

this is the HTML file I am using

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Application</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="com.myApp.Users/com.myApp.Users.nocache.js"></script>
<h1>Users Application</h1>
</body>
            <div id="3b2">
                <!-- when adding the below element it is working fine -->
                <!--<input type="text" placeholder="flight date" id="airlineCal" class="input-block-level">-->
            </div>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/triphop.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#airlineCal").datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        });

    });
</script>
</html>
```

and this is how I am creating the widget

```
final TextBox flightdateTextBox = new TextBox();
flightdateTextBox.getElement().setPropertyString("id", "airlineCal");
RootPanel.get("3b2").add(flightdateTextBox);
```

Comment: as a workaround , i inserted the input text in the html and started to read it in the gwt module itself using DOM library (((InputElement)(Element)DOM.getElementById("airlineCal")).getValue();)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this permanently , I used the date box picker instead of using a js date picker. by that I was able to access the date picker widget ..

```
// Create a date picker
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();

// Set the value in the text box when the user selects a date
datePicker.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {
  public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
    Date date = event.getValue();
    String dateString = DateTimeFormat.getMediumDateFormat().format(date);
    text.setText(dateString);
  }
});


// Add the widgets to the page
RootPanel.get().add(datePicker);
```

in order to get the date value use the getValue() method of the datePicker to return a java.util.Date

Comment: also you can apply styles to the date picker to make it pretty

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that `<input>` element is not created yet, when datepicker code is invoked. You may try to set timeout before getting input by id (which looks a bit ugly):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#airlineCal").datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        });
    }, 3000);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Load your JS after DOM is created.Override this method and call your JS if you are using UIBinder

```
@Override
    protected void onAttach() {
        super.onAttach();
        callJS();
    }


    private native void callJS()/*-{
  $(doc).ready(function () {
    $("#airlineCal").datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    });

    });

    }-*/;
```